# Call MFMailComposeViewController from a scrollview

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, email, xcode5

I'm new for iPhone development.  My app has a scrollview controller to capture user's information on three pages.  When the user completes all info and hits the email button, it should send an email, however, it does not now.

Below is my code and header file.  My header file does not implement the `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate` because it implements `UIScrollViewDelegate`.  I think my problem has to do with not implementing the `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate`.  How should I redesign this?

Header File

```
@interface DiveEdScrollViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

Call to the eMail:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[mc setSubject:subjectValue];
[mc setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];
[mc setToRecipients:diveContacts];
self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Comment: You can conform to multiple delegates in your .h file, that is:  "`<UIScrollViewDelegate, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>`".  Can you set a breakpoint in Xcode at that line where you first create your "`MFMailComposeViewController`" object.  Does Xcode ever stop there?

Answer (score 1):

Your view controller sub-class can adopt more than one protocol by separating with commas like this -

```
@interface DiveEdScrollViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate >
```

In your .m implement the method

`- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error`

As the documentation states:

> Your implementation of this method should dismiss the mail composition view. Implementation of this method is optional but expected.

Also you should check with the following class method first before attempting to show the mail composer like this (*to determine whether the device is configured for sending mail or not*) -

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
      [self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:NULL];
 }
```